# Component calling action creator before data from reducer can be sent

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a a react component which is supposed to render a list of users from an API. I am calling my action creator in my lifecycle hook method like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchUsers();
  }
```

I have checked and data is being returned and dispatched to the reducers in the correct format. But when I try to render these users in my component, nothing is being shown on the page:

```
renderUser(user) {
    return (
      <div className="card card-block">
        <h4 className="card-title">{user.name}</h4>
        <p className="card-text">{user.company.name}</p>
        <a className="btn btn-primary" href={user.website}>
          Website
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="user-list">{this.props.users.map(user => this.renderUser)}</div>
    );
  }
```

I get no errors or warnings, and my component is being rendered on the page after inspecting it, but is empty of content. When I try to do a few console logs, it seems that the componentWillMount() is being called before the reducers, and I don't know why. This means that my array of users after calling the fetchUsers() action creator is empty.

EDIT: Mapping the state and action creators to props

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { users: state.users };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(UserList);
```

I import all my actions at the top of the component. My reducer adds the payload (array) from the action creator to the app state.

```
export default function(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_USERS:
      return [...state, action.payload.data];
  }
  return state;
}
```

My action creator simply makes a get request and sends it off to the reducers:

```
export function fetchUsers() {
    const request = axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");
  return {
    type: FETCH_USERS,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

EDIT 2:

Example of JSON data received:

[image]

Comment: where are you mapping users as props?

Comment: use 'redux' chrome extension for debbuging. [refer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)

Comment: Do you have a link to this extension?

Comment: [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en)

Comment: Related https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/210

Answer (score 4):

You are not passing user data to the function

```
<div className="user-list">{this.props.users.map(user => this.renderUser(user))}</div>
```

Comment: Also, the `key` prop is missing in the returning div

Comment: When I do this, I receive an error on the page: 'bundle.js:21866 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined'

Comment: @Leth, double check your `users` array. The error is that `users.company` is undefined and so you cannot request `name` of undefined from `users.company.name`...

Comment: It is not empty when I console log it in the reducer, but the 'this.props.users' array is empty after I call the fetchUsers() action creator.

Comment: Yes, the actions foler is located in the same level as my component folder, and I use the the * to import all the actions at once.

Comment: If so, then no need to call as `this.props.fetchUsers()`

Comment: If I don't call the action creator from the component, none of my data is being returned and the reducers is not hit.

Comment: function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        users:state.users
    };
}
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({
        userSelected:userSelected
    },dispatch);

}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,matchDispatchToProps)(UserList);    this is a simple example to dispatch action..do like this

Answer (score 2):

You can try to insert a boolean like

```
 loaded: false,
```

to your initialState in your reducer and put them in your action

```
case USERS_LOAD :
loaded: true,
users: action.users,
... users,
```

Then You can insert something liket that in your component

```
const Users = ({ loaded, users }) => {
if (!loaded) {
return <div>Is loading ...</div>
}
    return (
    <p>Voici les utilisateurs :</p> 
{users.map(user => {
<li>{user}</li>}
  );
};
Users.propTypes = {
  users: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  loaded: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
};
```

to give a start to call your datas. I hope it can help you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If u look at the lifecycle the first one is componentwillmount().
It is called before render.
[refer](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/)

Comment: I do want to call the lifecycle method before the render to fill this.props.users with the data it needs to render. What other lifecycle method would you suggest instead?

Comment: where is this.props.fetchUsers() written

Comment: It is located in my index.js file in my actions folder. I have added the code to my post as an edit.